# How to hide debug messages in GAE logs?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

I know that debug logs are not displayed in the development environment by default (and should use command-line argument `--log_level=debug` to show them).
But production console displays them. Even if I define `Logs with minimum severity` equal to `Info`, still it shows debug messages (for the event where `Info` message is).

Is there any way to hide debug messages in production?

Answer (score 1):

`--log_level=debug` actually controls the loglevel emitted in the dev environment.

If you don't want debug level logs in production at all then read up in the python docs on setting the log level for your code base.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

But basically you call

`logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)`

in the top of each your handlers, or in appengine_conf.py to set it for everything.

Comment: I want to collect all level logs, but I would like to find a way to hide debug messages, when I don't need them (i.e. this is about display only). Probably, regex filter could help?